# how to keep the preferred syntax highlighting on for all new buffers opened in vim

Tags: vim, syntax, buffer, syntax-highlighting

I have set the syntax to a particular type in my vimrc file. Any files opened in a new window are set to this syntax, but in case I open new files from an existing window/buffer, they never borrow the same syntax.

I did come across some explanation with using bufdo, but then I believe this can be used to set the syntax on all currently open buffers. But I want any new buffers I create to also follow the same syntax.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want all new buffers to follow a single syntax, you could put something like this in your vimrc :

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead * set filetype=cpp
```

Where 'cpp' would determine the syntax highlighting for the file.

If you only wanted a certain file extension (e.g. '.cat'), you could use

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.cat set filetype=cpp
```

see `:help autocmd`  and potentially `:help ftplugin` `:help ftdetect` if you want different settings per filetype/extension.